# How to add validators in POA system (node-template) in runtime?

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

Can we add validators in runtime in POA system??(clone node-template)
Is this functionality available?? 
or we can only configure the validators before chain runs?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the validator before running a chain in your chain spec file.

You can find more details at Substrate tutorial. [Start a Private Network > Add Validators](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/private-network/#add-validators) says:

> To add validators:
> Modify the `aura` section to include **Sr25519** addresses.
> Modify the `grandpa` section to include **Ed25519** addresses and a voting weight.

Comment: Hi @dm4, can you please take a look at the Substrate StackExchange proposal and support it: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Answer (score 0):

You can just need to add pallet_session and create some mechanism to allow pallet_session to pick a new set of validators for every session.

There are some code examples to you take a look [here](https://github.com/gautamdhameja/substrate-validator-set)